# Please make sure that your site is pointed to same server on which you are running Let's Encrypt Client

Tags: lets-encrypt

I have easyengine and I don't renewed the certified in 90 days. So I try to renew after this period, and I have errors

Command I run:

> ee site update mysite --letsencrypt

```
ERROR : Cannot RENEW SSL cert !                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Your current cert already EXPIRED !
```

And in the log file, I run:

> tail /var/log/ee/ee.log

```
2017-02-16 13:29:01,999 (DEBUG) ee : Running command: date -d "`openssl x509 -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite/cert.pem -text -noout|grep "Not After"|cut -c 25-`" +%s                                                         
2017-02-16 13:29:02,009 (DEBUG) ee : Command Output: 1486812180                                                                                                                                                                           
,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Command Error:                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
2017-02-16 13:29:02,010 (ERROR) ee : Your current cert already EXPIRED !                                                                                                                                                                  
2017-02-16 13:29:02,010 (DEBUG) ee : Running command: date -d "`openssl x509 -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite/cert.pem -text -noout|grep "Not After"|cut -c 25-`"                                                             
2017-02-16 13:29:02,021 (DEBUG) ee : Command Output: Sat Feb 11 11:23:00 UTC 2017                                                                                                                                                         
,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Command Error:                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
2017-02-16 13:29:02,070 (ERROR) ee : Check logs for reason `tail /var/log/ee/ee.log` & Try Again!!!
```

What I can do? I already try to deactivate the certified using

> ee site update mysite --letsencrypt=off

And renew after this, using

> ee site update mysite --le=renew

JUST FOR TEST, The another error I receive after I removed all of conf of **mysite** is:

```
Please make sure that your site is pointed to same server on which you are running Let's Encrypt Client
```

But in command `sudo ee site info`, I receive this:

```
Nginx configuration      wp wpfc (enabled)                                                                                                                                                                                                
PHP Version              5.6                                                                                                                                                                                                              
HHVM                     enabled                                                                                                                                                                                                          
SSL                      disabled                                                                                                                                                                                                         


access_log               /var/www/mysite/logs/access.log                                                                                                                                                                      
error_log                /var/www/mysite/logs/error.log                                                                                                                                                                       
Webroot                  /var/www/mysite
```

That is, the 'site' is already pointed to the same server on running client of letsencrypt, and in my nginx.conf I already defined mysite.com and www.mysite.com.

Answer (score 2):

The problem indeed is with one of the Python packages being used by Let's Encrypt, but this error is being just "catched" not leaving that much of a trace.

I was able to renew expired certificates with Easy Engine just by setting the locales:

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8" && export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
```